# Shell script not picking the command line argument

Tags: shell, sh

Below is the snippet of my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh -e
ROOT=""
while getopts "r" optionName;
do case $optionName in
r)
    ROOT="$OPTARG"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Bad argument"
    exit
    ;;
esac
done
echo "ROOT=$ROOT"
```

it doesn't print the ROOT correctly, where is the problem?

```
$myscript.sh -r FOO
ROOT=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a colon after `r` if you want it to take an argument:

```
while getopts "r:" optionName
                ^
```

Comment: In the same script, how can I pass the argument as "-r" or as "--root"  ?